# joint_states messages different

Tags: ros, moveit, rosserial, joint-states, buffer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a custom 6DOF arm that I'm trying to interface with moveit. I have created the URDF and the model, and I have loaded it into rviz.

I have made a lot of progress with it I think. I'm using ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04

I subscribe to the joint_states topic on my arduino. Using the arduino code I am able to individually control each joint using the joint state sliders when I run the display.launch

I've completed the moveit configuration and it loads with no problems in rviz, and I can plan movements, etc.

however when my arduino subscribes to the joint_states topic at this point, I get errors in rosserial saying
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1479872259.522084] Message from ROS network dropped: message larger than buffer.

What is different with these messages than the ones generated from display.launch?

I performed some investigation and found something interesting:

This is the message from when I use moveit demo.launch

```
header: 
  seq: 954
  stamp: 
    secs: 1479873407
    nsecs: 957350015
  frame_id: ''
name: ['shoulder_base', 'upper_arm_shoulder', 'elbow_upper_arm', 'forearm_elbow', 'wrist_forearm', 'gripper_wrist', 'left_jaw_gripper', 'right_jaw_gripper']
position: [4.435017290525138e-05, 9.012486469545027e-05, 3.372531827300197e-05, 5.395870120266208e-05, 4.7403243313592324e-05, 0.8750411991072651, 0.0, 0.0]
velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
effort: []
```

and this is the message when I use display.launch

```
header: 
  seq: 228
  stamp: 
    secs: 1479873728
    nsecs: 257888078
  frame_id: ''
name: ['shoulder_base', 'upper_arm_shoulder', 'elbow_upper_arm', 'forearm_elbow', 'wrist_forearm', 'gripper_wrist', 'left_jaw_gripper', 'right_jaw_gripper']
position: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.2491756999999999, 0.0, 0.0]
velocity: []
effort: []
```

why the differences, and more importantly, can I make the position data the same data types/precision?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248653/joint_states-messages-different/) by [karlhm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/27384/karlhm76/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-23**:
Not an answer, but: `JointState` msgs are really typically used for *reporting* joint states, not for controlling them. Look into `JointTrajectory` and the related action servers. Ideally: write a `hardware_interface` for your controller and use `ros_control`. The `JointState` msgs ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-23**:
.. that you are seeing are probably those published by one of the *fake* controllers in MoveIt, which are just there to make it possible to visualise things without needing real hardware.

**Comment by [karlhm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/27384/karlhm76/) on 2016-11-23**:
Thanks for the info.
Yes I've been reading about this. I was simply trying to get the thing to work as easily as possible. I was reading that the fake controller published joint states and i already had something that worked with them, or so i thought.

**Comment by [karlhm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/27384/karlhm76/) on 2016-11-23**:
I've been having a few problems with getting started with the trajectory action server and catkin and netbeans. Not relevant here though. Even though I've made good progress with the setup I'm still fairly new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've decided to look into writing an action server for FollowJointTrajectory.

See how it goes I guess.
Thanks again.

---

Originally posted by [karlhm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/27384/karlhm76/) with karma: 43 on 2016-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-24**:
I'd really encourage you to take a look at writing a `hardware_interface` for your Arduino setup. Take a look at [ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate) by Dave Coleman. If you have communication with your Arduino setup, it shouldn't be too difficult.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-24**:
After you have the hardware interface implemented, you can re-use the `ros_control` action server (the `joint_trajectory_controller`) without writing any additional code.

**Comment by [karlhm76](https://answers.ros.org/users/27384/karlhm76/) on 2016-11-25**:
This is very useful information. Thanks so much